# Horizontal Rule - reducing the distance

Tags: article

Here is the M.W.E to draw a horizontal line across the page. Now, how do I reduce the space between the name and line. The gap is too high.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries SUBHAM SONI S.
\end{flushleft}
\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: put the box inside the environment. Or even use an `\hrule`

Comment: Usually these distances have a certain sense - the distance (as I remember) corresponds to the vertical spacing between two following paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `\makebox`  and you don't need even `flushleft`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%\begin{flushleft}    %% why do you need this?
\noindent
{\bfseries SUBHAM SONI S.}
\par
\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}   %% adjust -0.8
\noindent
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
%\end{flushleft}      %% why do you need this?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the resume, to write the content on the left and right side so the flush environments

Comment: @subhamsoni In that case better use `minipage`s and inside them use `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Such decorations frequently require lower level commands:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\bfseries SUBHAM SONI S.\\* % no page break
\kern2pt % some space
\hrule % a rule all the text width long
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]